# How To Create Helper For Date And Time Codeingiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I created a helper for an indonesian date but I need to convert from MySQL database value like this **2018-02-04 06:20:21** to **04-April-2018 06:20:21 WIB**

This Is My Helper Tanggal_helper.php

```
function TanggalIndo($date) {
    $BulanIndo = array("Januari", "Februari", "Maret", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Agustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Desember");
    $tahun  = substr($date, 0, 4);
    $bulan  = substr($date, 5, 2);
    $tgl    = substr($date, 8, 2);

    $result = $tgl . " " . $BulanIndo[(int) $bulan - 1] . " " . $tahun;
    return($result);
}
```

but This Helper just produces 4 April 2018.
please I need help..regards

Comment: Replace the `$result` assignment with  `$result = $tgl . " " . $BulanIndo[(int) $bulan - 1] . " " . $tahun . subStr($date, 10, strlen($date) - 10). " WIB";`

Comment: WHAT does WIB stand for ?

Comment: WIB is Surfix For Time local In Indonesia , WIB  = Waktu Indonesia Barat (Sumatra And Jawa Island)... Thanks For comment this works ...@deoKasuhal